# Detecting keyboard input

Tags: python, keyboard

I'm pretty new to Python and I am trying to detect when the f key  is pressed using the keyboard library. This is the code I am trying to run

```
import keyboard

keyboard.on_press_key('f',here())

def here():
    print('a')
```

However when specifying here() as the callback, I get a name not defined error on building

Comment: The declaration problem have been mentioned by others, but you must change "here()" in keyboard.on_press_key('f',here()) to "here", without the paranthesis. "here" is the address of the function, but "here()" gives the result of the function call immediately. And you must to pass the first value to the on_press_key().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are calling `here()`, it is not defined yet, so move the declaration of `here()` above your code.

Also, because `here` is supposed to be the callback, you need to pass it to `on_press_key` as a function reference.

```
import keyboard

def here():
    print('a')

keyboard.on_press_key('f', here)
```

Comment: Thanks, however now whenever I run this code it instantly prints out "a" even without pressing the 'f' key, any reason why this happens?

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned this in the answer, but because `here` is a callback, you need to pass it to `on_press_key` without the `()`, otherwise you are just giving `on_press_key` the return value of `here`  (not so useful!). I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Just move up you function `here()` declaration like so:

```
import keyboard

def here():
    print('a')

keyboard.on_press_key('f', here())
```

otherwise `here()` is not yet declared hence your error.

> NameError: global name '---' is not defined Python knows the purposes
>   of certain names (such as names of built-in functions like print).
>   Other names are defined within the program (such as variables). If
>   Python encounters a name that it doesn't recognize, you'll probably
>   get this error. Some common causes of this error include:
>
> Forgetting to give a variable a value before using it in another
>   statement Misspelling the name of a built-in function (e.g., typing
>   "inpit" instead of "input")

For python interpreter in your case when it's on line:

```
keyboard.on_press_key('f',here())
```

it doesn't know what `here()` is because it's not yet in memory.

Example:

```
$ cat test.py 
dummy_call()

def dummy_call():
    print("Foo bar")
$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    dummy_call()
NameError: name 'dummy_call' is not defined



$ cat test.py 
def dummy_call():
    print("Foo bar")

dummy_call()
$ python test.py 
Foo bar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import keyboard
IsPressed = False

# once you press the button('f') the function happens once
# when you release the button('f') the loop resets

def here():
    print('a')

while True:
    if not keyboard.is_pressed('f'):
        IsPressed = False
    while not IsPressed:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('f'):
            here()
            IsPressed = True

# or if you want to detect every frame it loops then:

def here():
    print('a')

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('f'):
        here()
```